# Not getting the oldvalues in test class - trigger coverage

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

I have  a test class where i am updating the stage to cover my test class. 
Issues is i am not getting the old value in after update trigger
All my debug are with new value :(

Below is my trigger

```
trigger updatePPGScopeStatus on PPG_Scope__c (after update) {
if(CommonUtility.check){
    CommonUtility.check = false;
    set<ID> projectScopeId = new set<ID>();
    //Set<String> statusSet = new Set<String>{'Cancelled','Lost','Superseded','Complete','No Bid'};
    list<Opportunity> inquiryLists = new list<Opportunity>();

    for(PPG_Scope__c projectScopeobj: trigger.new){   
        system.debug('old Scope :: scope id --- '+ Trigger.oldMap.get(projectScopeobj.id));
         system.debug('projectScopeobj :: scope id --- '+ projectScopeobj);
        system.debug('After Update Scope :: scope id --- '+ projectScopeobj.Stage__c);
        system.debug('Trigger.oldMap.get(projectScopeobj.id).Stage__c Scope :: scope id --- '+ Trigger.oldMap.get(projectScopeobj.id).Stage__c);
        if((Trigger.oldMap.get(projectScopeobj.id).Stage__c != projectScopeobj.Stage__c) && 
           ((projectScopeobj.Stage__c == 'Cancelled') || (projectScopeobj.Stage__c == 'Awarded-Lost') ||
            (projectScopeobj.Stage__c == 'Awarded-Lost & Entered') || (projectScopeobj.Stage__c == 'On hold')))
        { 
            projectScopeId.add(projectScopeobj.id);   // Put Id of Project Scope into Set.
        }
    }
    inquiryLists = [select id,Competitor__c,Skip_Competitor_Validation_Rule__c,StageName,PPG_Scope__c,PPG_Scope__r.Actual_Award_Date__c,PPG_Scope__r.Competitor__c,PPG_Scope__r.Stage__c, Quotation__c,Actual_Awarded_Date__c from Opportunity where PPG_Scope__c =: projectScopeId];
    Map<id, string> mapIdString = new Map<id, string>();   
    set<id> setId = new set<id>();
    if(inquiryLists != null && inquiryLists.size()>0){
        for(Opportunity inquiry : inquiryLists){
            if(!inquiry.StageName.contains('No Bid')
               && !inquiry.StageName.contains('Bid Submitted - Superseded')
               && !inquiry.StageName.contains('Complete - FEED Study')
               && !inquiry.StageName.contains('Awarded-Lost') 
               && !inquiry.StageName.contains('Cancelled')
               && !inquiry.StageName.contains('Awarded-Lost (Other Bid Successful)')){
                   if(inquiry.PPG_Scope__r.Stage__c == 'Cancelled'){
                       inquiry.StageName='Cancelled';
                       //updatedInquiryIdSet.add(inquiry.id);
                       mapIdString.put(inquiry.Quotation__c, inquiry.StageName);     
                       setId.add(inquiry.Quotation__c);
                   }
                   if((inquiry.PPG_Scope__r.Stage__c == 'Awarded-Lost') 
                      || (inquiry.PPG_Scope__r.Stage__c == 'Awarded-Lost & Entered')){
                            System.debug('After Update Scope:: Set Inquiry to Awarded-Lost');
                          inquiry.StageName='Awarded-Lost'; 
                          inquiry.Competitor__c = inquiry.PPG_Scope__r.Competitor__c;
                          inquiry.Actual_Awarded_Date__c = inquiry.PPG_Scope__r.Actual_Award_Date__c;
                          inquiry.Skip_Competitor_Validation_Rule__c = true;

                          //inquiry.Competitor__c=inquiry.PPG_Scope__r.Competitor__c; //REMOVED 27th July2018 
                          //updatedInquiryIdSet.add(inquiry.id);    
                          mapIdString.put(inquiry.Quotation__c, inquiry.StageName);
                          setId.add(inquiry.Quotation__c);
                      }
                   if((inquiry.PPG_Scope__r.Stage__c == 'On hold') 
                      && inquiry.StageName.contains('Bid Submitted')){
                          inquiry.StageName='On hold';
                          //pdatedInquiryIdSet.add(inquiry.id);     
                          mapIdString.put(inquiry.Quotation__c, inquiry.StageName);
                          setId.add(inquiry.Quotation__c);
                      }
               }
        } 
        checkFlowFromUpdateInquiryStatusTrigger.run = false;
        upsert inquiryLists;

        List<PPG_Quotation__c> quoteList = [select id, Status_Standalone__c from PPG_Quotation__c where id in :setId];
        if (quoteList != null && quoteList.size() > 0)  {
            for (PPG_Quotation__c quote : quoteList)    {
                if(quote.Status_Standalone__c != null){
                    if (!quote.Status_Standalone__c.contains('Bid Submitted - Superseded') && !quote.Status_Standalone__c.contains('Complete - FEED Study') && !quote.Status_Standalone__c.contains('Awarded - Lost') && !quote.Status_Standalone__c.contains('Cancelled') && !quote.Status_Standalone__c.contains('Awarded - Lost (Other Bid Successful)') )   {
                        if (mapIdString.get(quote.id) == 'Cancelled')   { quote.Status_Standalone__c = 'Cancelled'; }
                        if (mapIdString.get(quote.id) == 'Awarded-Lost')  { quote.Status_Standalone__c = 'Awarded - Lost'; }                
                        if (mapIdString.get(quote.id) == 'On hold' && quote.status_standalone__c.contains('Bid Submitted')) { quote.Status_Standalone__c = 'On Hold'; }
                    } }           
            }            
            checkFlowFromUpdateInquiryStatusTrigger.run = false;
            system.debug('After Update Scope :: #### UIS: quotes updated');
            update quoteList;
        }
    }

     map<Id, date> projectScopeIdMap = new map<Id, date>();
    list<Opportunity> newInquiryList = new list<Opportunity>();
    set<id>PPgscopeId=new set<id>();
    for(PPG_Scope__c projectScopeobj: trigger.new)
    {   
        PPgscopeId.add(projectScopeobj.Id);
        if (projectScopeobj.Set_Bid_Decision_Date_s_to_Award_Date__c == true)
        {
            projectScopeIdMap.put(projectScopeobj.id, projectScopeobj.Award_Date__c);
        }            
    }


} }
```

And Below is my Test Class

```
@isTest
public class updatePPGScopeStatus_test {
    public static testMethod void createProjectScope()
    {
        // Create a Account record.
        Account acc=new Account();
        acc.Name='Test';
        acc.Business_Type__c='NOC';
        insert acc;
       // Create a Project record.
        PPG_Project__c op=new PPG_Project__c();
        op.Name='Test1';
        op.Project_Location_2__c='Spain';
        op.Operator__c=acc.id;
        op.FID__c=system.today();
        op.Assigned_Region__c='APAC';
        insert op;
        // Create a scope record. 
        PPG_Scope__c pScope=new PPG_Scope__c();
        pScope.Award_Date__c=date.Today();
        pScope.Stage__c = 'Prospect';
        pScope.Operator_Project__c=op.id;
        pScope.Snapshot_Region__c='APAC';
        pScope.Sharing_Region__c='APAC';
        pScope.Estimated_Start_Coating_Date__c=date.Today();
        pScope.Estimated_Finish_Coating_Date__c=date.Today();
        pScope.Estimated_Value_Max__c=1000000;
        pScope.Estimated_Value_Min__c=1000000;
        pScope.Win_Probability__c='10';
        insert pScope;
        PPG_Scope__c pScope1=new PPG_Scope__c();
        pScope1.Id=pScope.id;
        pScope1.Stage__c='On hold';
       update pScope1;
        // Create a Inquiry record.
        Opportunity inq = new Opportunity();
        inq.Project_Name__c =op.id;
        inq.StageName='Bid Submitted';
        inq.Account=acc;
        inq.Name = 'test';
        inq.PPG_Scope__c=pScope.id;
        inq.Bid_Amount_Manual_Input__c=1000;
        inq.CloseDate=date.today();
        inq.Bidding_Group__c='Brazil';
        inq.Bid_Currency__c='USD';
        inq.Bid_Valid_Days__c ='15';
        inq.Bid_Amount_Manual_Input__c = 1000;
        inq.Bid_Submission_Date__c=date.today();
        inq.Bidder__c=UserInfo.getUserId();
        insert inq;
        PPG_Quotation__c quot = new PPG_Quotation__c();
        quot.Status_Standalone__c = 'Bid Submitted';
        quot.Master_Inquiry__c = inq.id;
        quot.Project_Name__c = op.id;
        quot.Date_Required__c = date.today();
        insert quot;
        quot.Date_Required__c = date.today()+1;
        update quot;
    }
}
```

The PPG Scope i am updating the Stage__c. 
[image: coverage error]

[image: Debug Log]

Comment: Is there anywhere you are updating `PPG_Scope__c` object?

Comment: no, But even if there is any update happening still i should get the old value right?

Comment: You have added recursive check. So just checking that might be issue. But it don't look like it is.

Comment: No its not again because of recursive check :( Checked it

Comment: You need to enter all other values except Inquiry stageName contains  :)

Comment: no luck I did that

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misinterpreting the cause of your lack of code coverage.

But first, the log issue: something else in your org is performing an update on `PPG_Scope__c` upon insert, and that update doesn't change `Stage__c`. That could be another trigger, or a workflow or process. Your recursion checker doesn't stop this because it's the *first* invocation of the trigger. Additionally, please note that the static-Boolean approach is the worst possible way to implement recursion protection and will cause a variety of problems in your code. (Search SFSE for more - there have been several questions on this subject in recent weeks).

Right now, it looks like (although the highlighting on your screenshot doesn't make much sense - are you running other tests?) the body of your `for` loop

```
    for(Opportunity inquiry : inquiryLists){
```

is not covered.

You derive `inquiryLists` from a query based on the `projectScopeId` set, which you populate from the `PPG_Scope__c` records that have updated Stage values.

But here's (a) problem: you perform the two relevant operations (inserting the Opportunity and updating the related `PPG_Scope__c` Stage) in the wrong order. The Stage update happens first, when there are no related Opportunities to locate. Once you insert the Opportunity, you perform no further Stage updates to the `PPG_Scope__c`. As a result, the trigger never updates with an Opportunity available, and your loop is never executed. Additionally, you create the Opportunity with the wrong `StageName` to match the `if` criteria inside the loop.

This is a good opportunity to step back and refactor. Right now, this is a smoke test that's just trying to run all the code to get test metrics, which is very bad practices. Consider instead breaking out your test code into a number of smaller test cases, each of which exercises exactly one code path - such as "what happens when a `PPG_Scope__c` is updated with multiple Opportunities?" "What happens when a `PPG_Scope__c` is updated with no Opportunities?" "What happens if the new `PPG_Scope__c` is not one of the values that should update the Opportunities?" (This would be a negative test).

You can move all of your data creation into an `@testSetup` method and write several very small test cases that query the data you create, make an update as necessary to create the situations mentioned above, and then *make assertions about the results* to show that your code is doing what it's expected to do.

For more about writing good unit tests, see the resources below.

- [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests)
- [Apex Testing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing) on Trailhead.
- [Three-part series](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/05/why-we-test.html) on the Salesforce Developer Blog.

Answer (score -1):

did you try inserting the opportunity before updating the PPG_Scope__c pScope1 record? I would insert the opportunity first, and then update the stage of the PPG_Scope__c record. Also, you do not have to recreate the PPG_Scope__c record to update it, just do: pScope.Stage__c='On hold'; update pScope. After an insert statement, Salesforce populates the Id.